# How to get the length of every word in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I'm new to coding and have been given this question to solve.

The question I have been given is this;

Create a function that takes a string and returns an array of the lengths of each word in the string.

```
 E.g. 'pineapple and black bean curry' => [9, 3, 5, 4, 5]
```

The code that I have written is this;

```
function getWordLengths(str) {
    let len = []
    let words = str.split()
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        len.push(words[i])}
    
    return len
}
```

My code will be run against this test;

```
describe("getWordLengths", () => {
 it("returns [] when passed an empty string", () => {
   expect(getWordLengths("")).to.eql([]);
 });
 it("returns an array containing the length of a single word", () => {
   expect(getWordLengths("woooo")).to.eql([5]);
 });
 it("returns the lengths when passed multiple words", () => {
   expect(getWordLengths("hello world")).to.eql([5, 5]);
 });
 it("returns lengths for longer sentences", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("like a bridge over troubled water")).to.eql([
     4,
     1, 
     6,
     4,
     8,
     5
    ]);
 });
});
```

Dose anyone have any suggestion of haw to make my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `.split()` to `.split(' ')` and `len.push(words[i])` to `len.push(words[i].length)`.

```js
const text = 'pineapple and black bean curry'; //[9, 3, 5, 4, 5]

function getWordLengths(str) {
  let len = [];
  let words = str.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    len.push(words[i].length);
  }
  return len;
}

console.log(getWordLengths(text));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string#split` and then use map to get the length of each word.

```js
let string = 'pineapple and black bean curry',
    result = string.split(/\s+/).map(({length}) => length);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any `separator` to your `split` function.

So, [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string at every `" "`, then calculate the `length` of each word from the resulting array using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let string = 'pineapple and black bean curry';

console.log(string.split(' ').map(a => a.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

`\b` in a regex expression to split words.

```js
let line='pineapple and black bean curry';
let results=line.match(/\b[^\s]+?\b/g).map(r=>r.length);
console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this buddy.

1. The simplest way would probably be to do as you attempted, i.e., to use the `.split()` feature. It works only when used rightly. You have forgotten to split the string based on a **separator**. And here since you are interested in individual words, the separator should be a space. `' '`. just map the lengths of the words onto a new array and print it out.

```js
let string = 'pineapple and black bean curry';
let words = string.split(' ');
console.log(words.map(word => word.length))
```

2. If you don't want to use `map` or `split` functionalities and want to do it using straightforward manual ways, you can do the following: In this , you just keep a counter variable which you increment as long as you don't encounter a space or end of the string and then reset it at the start of the next word.

```js
let string = 'pineapple and black bean curry';
let count = 0, count_array = [];
let x = string.length;

for(i=0;i<=x;i++){
if(string[i]==' ' || string[i]=='\0' || i==x){
count_array.push(count);
count=0;
}
else{
count++;
}
}

console.log(count_array);
```